# How to use MP labels with PK fonts?

Tags: metapost

Run `mf \\mode=localfont\; input test.mf` on the following file:

```
mode_setup;

beginchar("e",10pt#,7.5pt#,2.5pt#);
pickup pencircle scaled (.4pt+blacker);
draw fullcircle scaled .2w shifted (w/2,(h+d)/2-d);
draw fullcircle scaled .6w shifted (w/2,(h+d)/2-d);
draw fullcircle scaled w shifted (w/2,(h+d)/2-d);
endchar;

end
```

Now run `mpost test.mp` on the following file:

```
prologues := 3;
beginfig(1);
label.lrt(btex \font\x=test \x e etex, (0,0));
endfig;
end
```

Output contains this warning:

> Warning: font test cannot be found in any fontmapfile!

How to use PK font in MetaPost labels?

Comment: As well as putting the .tfm and .pk files in the right place:  https://texfaq.org/FAQ-instmffont , you need to update the psfonts map files which metapost uses.  The MP log will tell you which one you are using.

Comment: But in the example you show it would be much simpler just to draw directly in Metapost rather than making a font and using that via TeX....

Comment: @Thruston Current directory is always searched by default (in TexLive at least).

Comment: @Thruston I need to use a pk font which does not exist as pfb. This metafont character is just an example.

Comment: right - but you need to have a line in psfonts.map that points to your pk font.

Comment: https://www.tug.org/fonts/fontinstall-personal.html

Comment: @Thruston I cannot understand which line to add to `psfonts.map`...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't. metapost doesn't handle pk-fonts. Here you can find an rather old quote about it:
https://tug.org/pipermail/metapost/2007-November/001104.html:

> There is absolutely no code in metapost at all to deal with bitmaps.
>
> If I had wanted to support pk files, I would have had to call mktexpk just like dvips & pdftex do. I decided not to do that, as the use of bitmapped fonts in eps files is totally opposite to the idea of having a scalable vector graphic.

Comment: I created a pfb variant of pk font with `mftrace` and now I can use this font in MP labels (with `prologues:=0;` pk fonts work because processing is done in `dvips`).